# Struts how to prepopulate edit form with object

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have a simple entity called Brand:

```
public class Brand{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I have a jsp where this data displayed:

```
        <p>
            <label for="id"><s:text name="brand.view.id" /></label>
            <c:out value="${requestScope.brand.id}"></c:out>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="name"><s:text name="brand.view.name" /></label>
            <c:out value="${requestScope.brand.name}"></c:out>
        </p>
        <p>
            <s:a action="edit_display" namespace="/brand"><s:text name="brand.view.button.edit" />
            </s:a>
        </p>
```

And in this jsp page you see that there is a button "Edit" that will get user to ther editing form. I want this form to be populated with Brand data.

Now in `struts.xml` I have the next mapping:

```
<package name="brand" namespace="/brand" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*_display">
            <result name="success" type="dispatcher">/WEB-INF/view/brand/{1}.jsp
            </result>
        </action>
        <action name="view" class="com.example.action.brand.ViewBrandAction">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/brand/view.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="edit" class="com.example.action.brand.EditBrandAction">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/brand/edit.jsp</result>
        </action>
</package>
```

So the logic now is the next: When User clicks on `/brand/edit_display` link no action will be called and thus empty form will be displayed.

What options do I have if I want to pass objects beetween jsp's ? Action Chaining, ajax on edit page, another action `PopulateEditBrandAction`, build query param string or maybe there is something better ?

Because I know the object that user want to edit - can I just simply pass it ?

Comment: Why not to add a class to the action that loads an object?

Comment: @RomanC you mean like `PopulateEditBrandAction` ? I just thought that another call to database will not be needed.

Comment: You don't need to pass an object to another action/jsp, there's no reason to do it, the only reason might be if you need that object back.

Comment: Just make a method for intilize the object in a EditBrandAction. Get that user id as a parameter in it and then load the object by Id and pass to jsp page.

<action name="edit" class="com.example.action.brand.EditBrandAction" method="initilize">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/brand/edit.jsp</result>
        </action>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to edit_display creates a new request with a new action context. If you want different requests to share the same data, you have to use the session.

The Struts2 way to do it would be to implement `org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware` in your Action.

Save the object in `ViewBrandAction`:

```
userSession.put("some_namespace_brand", brand);
```

Then you can access your object in the jsp by using:

```
<s:property value="#session.some_namespace_brand.id" />
```

Or implement what you called `PopulateEditBrandAction` to get the object back:

```
brand = (Brand) userSession.get("some_namespace_brand");
```

Be sure to read the documentation on this as it addresses the security risks of making the session accessible through a request parameter. https://struts.apache.org/docs/http-session.html